# Visual Studio 2015 Cordova Project, save automatically delete file

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile, visual-studio-2015, save

I use Visulal Studio 2015 Cordova project and install jquery mobile. But when I click save button , the two file of cordova.js or index.html will be automically deleted. Does somebody meet the same problem?